# Xamarin Forms File Result is Null when Pick File in FilePicker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, readfile, filepicker

File selection is made with picker in my project where I make Xamarin Forms. The problem is that it always **returns null**.

my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

my code

```
            var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/octet-stream" } }
                });
            var options = new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Please select a .DB file",
                FileTypes = customFileType,
            };
            try
            {
                var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options); //<= Returns null. But i selected file
                if (result != null)
                {
                    if (result.FileName.EndsWith("db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {

                        var fileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(result.FullPath);
                        string path = App.path + @"/" + result.FileName;
                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileByte);


                        StartViewModel viewModel = new StartViewModel(new StartPage());
                        App.Current.MainPage = viewModel.View;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // The user canceled or something went wrong
            }
```

my Output Logs

```
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'StartPage.xaml.cs:119,1' to void PasswordSaver.Views.StartPage.<PickAndSaveFile>d__5.MoveNext () [0x0008c].
[Timeline] Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:400995680
[Timeline] Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:400995764
[DecorView[]] getWindowModeFromSystem  windowmode is 1
[DecorView] createDecorCaptionView windowingMode:1 mWindowMode 1 isFullscreen: true
[Activity] Slow Operation: Activity com.developerPazl.passwordStore/crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity onActivityResult took 8205ms
[Looper] PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=1443 plan=09:41:11.653 late=2ms wall=8217ms running=57ms runnable=29ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159 procState=2
[Choreographer] Frame time is 0.02849 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
[Choreographer] Frame time is 0.009386 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.
```

All packages have been updated. But there is no progress. Your answer will be appreciated.

### Edit There is progress

Ok, I'm narrowing down the problem. I opened the simulator there, this code continued to work without any problems. But the problem continues on the `Redmi Note 9 Pro` device. That doesn't explain how it behaves on specific devices. `File Picker` not working on certain devices, reason unknown

Comment: You might need to first do a ["Run-time permission check"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#runtime-permission-checks-in-android-60) to verify that the user has accepted that permission.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Xamarin.Essentials will throw an exception if permissions are missing

Comment: Are you certain a `.DB` file satisfies the picker options of `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Maybe test first with a simple text file. ALSO, where are you calling the code shown from - a button command? Just in case, consider wrapping the call in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, to be sure you satisfy this: *"All methods must be called on the UI thread ..."* from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this didn't work for me. I appreciate your help. but the method can't return value, I created a separate method but that didn't work either.

Comment: @AndrewH yes this code was working before. It stopped working for unknown reason.

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT i am edit question. added Output info

Comment: What Android version or API number is on the phone? If different than the emulator, set up an emulated device with same API number.

Comment: The code was working previously? That’s a very important detail - always mention that when describing a problem. Did it stop after updating VS or XForms? Manually uninstall app from device, to be sure you have a clean start.

Comment: Also, delete project’s obj and bin folders, to be sure it rebuilds from scratch.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Clearing bin obj is the first thing I do. Yes, this code was working before on the problematic device. After the problem became clear, I decided to Update XForms. The device name is Redmi Note 9 Pro ANDROID-11. API-30

Comment: Did you make any changes to your APP before the problem occurred? Has this problem occurred on other devices

Comment: @EminNiftiyev if it is a device-specific problem, have you considered trying a different file picker Android app? It could be the current default app for file browsing has an issue with the filter you've provided or something else.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT no i dont any change.

Comment: @AndrewH yes i tried, same problem occured in all of them. I tried Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker and Xam.FilePicker

Comment: Did you **Manually uninstall app from device**? Or might even need to use Tools / Android / adb command line `adb uninstall com.yourcompany.yourappname` to be sure previous debug version didn’t leave something incompatible behind.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev I do not refer to the NuGet plugin for picking files. I refer to the Android system application for browsing your device file system. The file browser app on your Note 9 may have an incompatibility or other issue.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i tried how you said. But nothing working. Thanks for your interest

Comment: @AndrewH Maybe such problems can occur on MIUI systems. I can't test because I don't have any other MIUI systems.

Comment: @AndrewH - are you suggesting they write code in Android project that uses a different native file picker? How would they do that? Can you provide more specifics or links?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Android allows users to pick a "default app" for different actions, like opening files. This is a user action and the developer has no say in what app the user uses to select the file.